# I have problem installing pyqt5 tools with pip. any solution?

Tags: python, pip, pyqt5

I tried to install pyqt5-tools with pip but this error occurred:

```
ERROR: pyqt5==5.14.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/5b/e760ec4f868cb77cee45b4554bf15d3fe6972176e89c4e3faac941213694/PyQt5-5.14.0.tar.gz#sha256=0145a6b7de15756366decb736c349a0cb510d706c83fda5b8cd9e0557bc1da72 (from pyqt5-tools) has a pyproject.toml file that does not comply with PEP 518: 'build-system.requires' contains an invalid requirement: 'sip >=5.0.1 <6'
```

I already have installed pyqt5 without problem.

Comment: @john-hen The difference could be in OS, Python and pip versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Install Python 3.8** from official python website it's on the **bottom of the page:** https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380/

Then install the package **with Python 3.8** instead of the version you are currently using like this:

> py -3.8 -m pip install pyqt5-tools

This worked for me, and will hopefully work for you too :)

Note that you will need to **use python 3.8 for running a code** :C

Comment: thank you for your answer.it solved the problem!But now I can not find the execution file to open qt designer.how should I open it up?

Comment: pyqt5-tools designer / pyqt5-tools designer --help